# Can't find the function body in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I recently started working on a project that has been in development for some time now. The problem is this - in the web site page, a have a frame (amongst 4 others) in a frameset which contains the SVG map object (the whole site is GIS based). Also, in the same frame, there is a icon for opening the form in which user can choose a number of filters, and after he presses a button, the map refreshes and the area of influence around some key points on the map are drawn.

What i need to do is to open that form in a new (popup) window and not in the same frame where the map is. I did that this way:

```
onclick="window.open('zi.aspx','form1','width=700,height=500,left=350,top=100')"
```

This works fine. But then, when i enter the filters and hit Generate button, i get this error:

```
'parent.frames.map' is null or not an object
```

with the reference to zi.aspx. Now i know that this error is because i changed the form from opening in the same frame as map to opening it in a popup window, but i just can't find anywhere in the code where can i modify it. Before my changes, the code was just this:

```
 onclick="showZi();"
```

and that is the function i can't find anywhere. Any ideas? How can i make this work, to make a map with filters drawn after the user has chosen appropriate ones from the popup window form?  I should mention that this image link is in the ASP.NET table, with standard runat="server" command.

Comment: Open the inspection with google chrome, and inside the inspection there is a search - type showZi and will find it for you in all the loaded files on your web.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you're opening a new window from javascript. Your problem is that you're trying to access the parent window by using the 'window.parent' property. This is wrong, you'll need to instead use '**window.opener**' property. E.g.:

```
window.opener.frames.map
```

Comment: The window.parent property is used for frames as opposed to new windows.